# JAVA: Use While Loop to print out character as many times as the number read in

Tags: java

Hello I'm having issues on my intro to Computer Science Lab Work:

CharacterLine.java: Write a program that prints a line of characters. Prompt the user to enter a character and then ask for a number. If the number is lies than 1 or greater than 80, tell the user then to exit the program. Use a while Loop to print out the character as many times as the number read in. 
Example:
Please enter a character: &
Please enter a number: 15
Your line: &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharacterLine

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.print("Please enter a character: ");
        String character = kb.next();
        int charact = character.length();

        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        number = kb.nextInt();

        while ( number <= 80 && number >= 1 ){

            if ( number <= 80 && number >= 1 ) {
                int bills = (charact * number);
                System.out.println("Your line: " + charact++);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("error.");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            number = kb.nextInt();
        }
        if ( number > 80 ){
            System.out.println("That number is too large");
        }
        else if ( number < 1 ){
            System.out.println("That number is too small");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

I am having issues in knowing how I can multiply the number that the user inputted and make the output the number times the one letter that the user inputted.

Thanks,
William

Comment: You use that many times and print your character inside it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use loop to iterate for `given` number of times.. and print the character..

```
if ( number <= 80 && number >= 1 ) {

   char myChar = '*';

   // This while loop will run 15 times if value of number is 15..
   while(number > 0) {
        System.out.println(myChar);
        number--;   // Decrement the value of `number` by 1.
   }
}
```

**The above while loop says:**

> While the value of number is greater than 0, execute the loop, and
>   print the statement inside it.. After printing, decrement the value of
>   number by 1, and check the condition once again... Continue this
>   process while `number > 0`

Comment: He's supposed to use a while loop. See exercise description.

Comment: No problem, wanted to give you the chance to correct your answer :)

Comment: Hi Rohit, 
So does "number--:" make it so when they input the number say "15", the number-- produces the 15 in letters?

Comment: @BillyZimmerman.. No its a decrement operator.. You didn't read my comment in the code.. You have to add the statement to print.. That loop will run 15 times and print the character 15 times..

Comment: @BillyZimmerman.. I highly recommend you to start reading this Java Tutorial: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ .. Read every thing.. Don't skip a single point..

Comment: @Rohit check your answer ... must be "while number > 0" instead of "until number > 0"

Comment: @Fildor.. Ahh.. you have helped me again.. may be you deserve some treat here..  what say??  :)

Comment: @Fildor. Ok.. So, just for collections yeah.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(number>0){
            System.out.print(character);
            number--;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Robert,
So the number--; produces the number of characters from the users input of a number?

Comment: No. `number--` is "syntactic sugar" for `number = number - 1;`. `print` will output the caracter 1 time. And the while loop will repeat this `number` times.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the task. You are **not** supposed to multiply. You are supposed to print a certain character given by the user *as many times* he tells you, using a `while` loop. So Inputs "a" and "4" would result in output "aaaa".

Comment: oh okay. So it isn't possible to multiply the number with the string to produce the repeated amount?

Comment: Not in Java :) That's why you're supposed to use a loop.

Comment: By the way: you didn't even do that. You multiplied the charcter's length with the number entered. And then you did not use it ...